# intel xeon hardware cache events not supported

Tags: linux, intel, cpu-cache, perf

I am trying to use perf tool to measure performance on some program.
For some reason perf stat doesn't support hardware cache events.
I'm using intel xeon e5-2620 (haswell) processor.
I read in some forum that the event codes might have been changed for this cpu and that is why perf doesn't support these events.
I tried using perfmon2 to find the raw events but with no luck.
Does anybody know how to find the correct raw events for hardware cache events for this cpu?
I'm specifically interested in L1-dcache-loads and L1-dcache-stores but a generic solution will be better.
I am using Linux version 3.0.101-0.47.52-default.

Comment: Have you checked the Haswell list here? - http://oprofile.sourceforge.net/docs/intel-haswell-events.php
I'd suspect it's mem_uops_retired.all_loads, but check to make sure

Comment: what output do you get from `perf list`?  I have a Haswell system (not e5-2620 though) and the events you are interested in work fine for me.

Comment: perf list shows me the same list on every system

Answer (score 0):

i got some help on intel developers forum
https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/563469

the events are:
L1 Data Cache Loads (Event 0xD0, Umask 0x81) 
L1 Data Cache Stores (Event 0xD0, Umask 0x82)